ERROR Connection error : [TypeError: Network request failed]
I developed a react-native application with API rest (node expressjs in backend) the app works fine on web but when I try on my phone (Android) with Expo Go I get this error:

PS: the server runs on a ubuntu wsl (172.24.238.98/20) and my PC (192.168.x.x) my phone is connected to the same WiFi as the PC.
How do I set it up?
I tried to replace for example:
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/login

by
const response = await fetch('http://192.168.x.x:3000/login' 

(windows's ip),
but still the error.
